# Using method in protocol

Tags: swift, protocols, selector

I've created a protocol and an extension of the protocol:

```
protocol SomeProtocol: class {
    var someView: UIView { get set }

    func handlePan(recognizer: UIPanGestureRecognizer)
}

extension SomeProtocol where Self: UIViewController {
    func handlePan(recognizer: UIPanGestureRecognizer) {
        // implementation
    }
}

class SomeViewController: UIViewController, SomeProtocol {

    var someView = UIView()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        someView.frame = CGRect(x: 100, y: 200, width: 50, height: 50)
        someView.addGestureRecognizer(UIPanGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(handlePan)))
        someView.backgroundColor = .black

        view.addSubview(someView)
    }
}
```

But this is giving me the error where im creating the `UIPanGestureRecognizer`:

> Error: Argument of '#selector' refers to instance method 'handlePan(recogniser:)' that is not exposed to Objective-C

Is there a way to fix this instead of adding `handlePan` method in the view controller?

Comment: Since the method takes a parameter the signature is supposed to be `#selector(handlePan(_:))`

Comment: @vadian Actually the formal signature would be `#selector(handlePan(recognizer:))` – although given that `handlePan` is unambiguous, `#selector(handlePan)` is perfectly acceptable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to annotate your protocol with `@objc` to expose it to the Objective-C runtime library:

```
@objc protocol SomeProtocol: class { //...
```

Comment: Now xcode is complaining about `Non'@objc' property ... does not satisfy requirement of '@objc' protocol` for my other properties. Is there another way without having to add `@objc`?

Comment: Nope, you're trying to use a feature of the Objective C runtime with your Swift Protocol. The protocol needs to be exposed to the Objective C runtime. You'll have to sort that error out. Search around on SO, or post a new question if required.

Comment: Yeah, the problem with this now is that Objective-C cannot see protocol extensions ;)

Comment: Thanks for the help and information. I'll accept this question and try to find alternatives for this.